# Загрузка изображения

Tags: html, php

Здравствуйте, у меня есть код загрузки изображения и записи переменной в файл bd.dat, но если пользователь загрузит изображение с кириллицей, то оно может быть некорректно в отображении на сайте. Помогите разобраться, как можно сделать так, чтобы любое имя переводилось в латинское, а если уже есть латиница, то оставить так, как есть, есть функция перекодировки

```
function translitIt($str)
{
    $tr = array(
        "А" => "A",
        "Б" => "B",
        "В" => "V",
        "Г" => "G",
        "Д" => "D",
        "Е" => "E",
        "Ж" => "J",
        "З" => "Z",
        "И" => "I",
        "Й" => "Y",
        "К" => "K",
        "Л" => "L",
        "М" => "M",
        "Н" => "N",
        "О" => "O",
        "П" => "P",
        "Р" => "R",
        "С" => "S",
        "Т" => "T",
        "У" => "U",
        "Ф" => "F",
        "Х" => "H",
        "Ц" => "TS",
        "Ч" => "CH",
        "Ш" => "SH",
        "Щ" => "SCH",
        "Ъ" => "",
        "Ы" => "YI",
        "Ь" => "",
        "Э" => "E",
        "Ю" => "YU",
        "Я" => "YA",
        "а" => "a",
        "б" => "b",
        "в" => "v",
        "г" => "g",
        "д" => "d",
        "е" => "e",
        "ж" => "j",
        "з" => "z",
        "и" => "i",
        "й" => "y",
        "к" => "k",
        "л" => "l",
        "м" => "m",
        "н" => "n",
        "о" => "o",
        "п" => "p",
        "р" => "r",
        "с" => "s",
        "т" => "t",
        "у" => "u",
        "ф" => "f",
        "х" => "h",
        "ц" => "ts",
        "ч" => "ch",
        "ш" => "sh",
        "щ" => "sch",
        "ъ" => "y",
        "ы" => "yi",
        "ь" => "",
        "э" => "e",
        "ю" => "yu",
        "я" => "ya"
    );
    return strtr($str, $tr);
}
$_FILES['image'] = strtr($_FILES['image']);
$tempfile        = $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'];
$newname         = $_FILES['image']['name'];
if (is_uploaded_file($tempfile)) {
    move_uploaded_file($tempfile, $newname);
}
$settings     = "Имя:::Фамилия:::$photoname";
$settingsfile = fopen("bd.dat", "w");
fputs($settingsfile, $settings);
fclose($settingsfile);
```

Answer (score 3):

Для транслитерации пользуюсь вот такой функцией:

```
function translit( $string, $t=false ){

    $replace = array(
        "'"=>"", "`"=>"",
        "а"=>"a","А"=>"a", "б"=>"b","Б"=>"b", "в"=>"v","В"=>"v", "г"=>"g","Г"=>"g", "д"=>"d","Д"=>"d",
        "е"=>"e","Е"=>"e", "ж"=>"zh","Ж"=>"zh", "з"=>"z","З"=>"z", "и"=>"i","И"=>"i", "й"=>"y","Й"=>"y",
        "к"=>"k","К"=>"k", "л"=>"l","Л"=>"l", "м"=>"m","М"=>"m", "н"=>"n","Н"=>"n", "о"=>"o","О"=>"o",
        "п"=>"p","П"=>"p", "р"=>"r","Р"=>"r", "с"=>"s","С"=>"s", "т"=>"t","Т"=>"t", "у"=>"u","У"=>"u",
        "ф"=>"f","Ф"=>"f", "х"=>"h","Х"=>"h", "ц"=>"c","Ц"=>"c", "ч"=>"ch","Ч"=>"ch", "ш"=>"sh","Ш"=>"sh",
        "щ"=>"sch","Щ"=>"sch", "ъ"=>"","Ъ"=>"", "ы"=>"y","Ы"=>"y", "ь"=>"","Ь"=>"", "э"=>"e","Э"=>"e",
        "ю"=>"yu","Ю"=>"yu", "я"=>"ya","Я"=>"ya", "і"=>"i","І"=>"i", "ї"=>"yi","Ї"=>"yi", "є"=>"e","Є"=>"e"
    );

    if ($t) $replace[' '] = "_";

    $string = iconv("UTF-8","UTF-8//IGNORE",strtr($string,$replace));
    if ($t) $string = preg_replace("/[^A-z_\-]/", '', $string );

    return $string;
}
```

Но для имён файлов лучше использовать уникальные генерируемые имена (можно из цифр). Это избавит от проблемы кеширования.

Answer (score 2):

Написал Вам небольшую [функцию](http://codepad.org/p6cYeq6j). Коллизии в ней - недостаток Вашего словаря. По 1му параметру получает строку, по второму - в какую литерацию конвертировать. "en" значит что исходный текст на русском, "ru", что на английском. Если вы оставите "en" с латинскими символами - строка не изменится.

Соответственно применять необходимо к `$newname = $_FILES['image']['name'];`.