# Перевод русских букв на латиницу PHP

Tags: php

Есть ли такая функция или способ в `PHP` чтобы перевести русские буквы на английские?

Comment: Функции стопудово нет. А способов транслитерации предостаточно. Как и готовых кодов... только стандартов транслитерации ни разу не один, и соответственно результаты они дают несколько неодинаковые - помни об этом.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/158104/186083 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/658067/186083

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Встроенной функции нет. Но можно использовать готовые в интернете их куча.
Например

```
function translit($s) {
  $s = (string) $s; // преобразуем в строковое значение
  $s = trim($s); // убираем пробелы в начале и конце строки
  $s = function_exists('mb_strtolower') ? mb_strtolower($s) : strtolower($s); // переводим строку в нижний регистр (иногда надо задать локаль)
  $s = strtr($s, array('а'=>'a','б'=>'b','в'=>'v','г'=>'g','д'=>'d','е'=>'e','ё'=>'e','ж'=>'j','з'=>'z','и'=>'i','й'=>'y','к'=>'k','л'=>'l','м'=>'m','н'=>'n','о'=>'o','п'=>'p','р'=>'r','с'=>'s','т'=>'t','у'=>'u','ф'=>'f','х'=>'h','ц'=>'c','ч'=>'ch','ш'=>'sh','щ'=>'shch','ы'=>'y','э'=>'e','ю'=>'yu','я'=>'ya','ъ'=>'','ь'=>''));
  return $s; // возвращаем результат
}

echo translit("Получилось!");
```